# What is the simplest way to put pass an array of values into a parameter of TVF

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, parameters, user-defined-functions

**Objective:**

I would like to have a parameter in my function to allow the user to input a list of values. Ideally, the simplest solution ... Note: I dont have permissions to create tables in dbs.

**Situation:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnExample
(
    @StartDate AS Date -- Parameter 1
    @ParameterArray AS ... -- This would be the parameter that accepts a list of values
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
...code...
GO
```

Not sure how to pass several parameters in a TVF but this is how I would view the solution

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.fnExample ('2019-01-01') and ([list of values])
```

Comment: Use a Table Type Parameter.

Comment: In case you don't have permission to create the requisite type for a TVP, [here](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) is a more extensive discussion of the alternatives.

Comment: "I dont have permissions to create tables in dbs" Do you have permissions to create user defined table types?

Comment: @ZoharPeled not sure what this is how can i test it

Comment: You don't have permissions to create tables, but do for functions?

Comment: @Larnu yes, dont ask mewhy lol

Comment: Well, just try to run larnu's answer. If you get a result and not errors, then you have your answer. If you get a permission error, then it's time to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I would advice against using the splitting function in the article linked before. I suggest that you look for DelimitedSplit8k for a better performing function that will run several times faster.

Comment: It's logical to be able to create functions but not tables. Functions are code, but tables need planning on storage and proper design that some DBAs might want to control more carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a table type parameter, you can do something like the following:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SomeArray AS TABLE (SomeInt int); --Create the TYPE
GO
 --Now the Function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Example (@StartDate date, @Array dbo.SomeArray READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SomeInt, @StartDate) AS NewDate
    FROM @Array

GO

--Now to test
--Declare the TYPE
DECLARE @Array dbo.SomeArray;
--Insert the data
INSERT INTO @Array (SomeInt)
VALUES(7),(1654),(13);

--Test the function
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Example(GETDATE(), @Array) E;
GO

--Clean up
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Example;
DROP TYPE dbo.SomeArray;
```

How to `JOIN`:

```
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN @Array A ON YT.SomeInt = A.SomeInt
```

How to use `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Array A WHERE YT.SomeInt = A.SomeInt)
```

Comment: why in the return of the function you put FROM @Array. Where am i putting my whole query?

Comment: This is an example @RogerSteinberg, I can't tell you how to write your query as you have replaced it with `...code...`. I can't rewrite something i don't have access to. :) You'll have to fill in the blank on how to use the Table-Type parameter in your query.

Comment: So assuming the '@'Array is a list of ids . I can pass the '@'Array within my where statement?

Comment: You'd need to use a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS`. It's not a list, it's a table.

Comment: obviously... makes sense now. so that's how i can pass a list of values by joining to a type table that i'm creating correct?

Comment: Somehow when i joined it to the parameter. i get an empty result set.
when i replace the parameter with the exact same values as such: INNER JOIN (VALUES (1),(2)) A(SomeInt) on mytable.SomeInt=A.SomeInt
it works.

Comment: My only guess is you have done *something* wrong, @RogerSteinberg. I can't see what you see, so there's nothing I offer more than that. unless you can provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: should i insert an edit section to my question and input what i tried following your solution?

Comment: If you can supply a fiddle on the comments I'll happy have a look later.

Comment: Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f413cca1e0375e50b4fd5d542669002

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193413/discussion-between-roger-steinberg-and-larnu).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on SQL Server 2016+ the simplest way is to use JSON:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnExample
(
    @StartDate AS Date -- Parameter 1
    @ParameterArray AS NVARCHAR(MAX) -- pass JSON Array like '[1,2,3,4,5]'
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT,j.value) AS [ID] FROM OPENJSON(@ParameterArray) j;
GO
```